# selenium unable to open firefox browser

Tags: firefox, selenium

Trying to execute a TestSuite in Selenium that has to launch firefox browser, but this fails to work in any browser other than internet explorer...

selenium-server version--->1.0.1

firefox version--->14.0.1

MY OUTPUT:

> C:\selenium\lib>java -jar selenium-server-1.0.1.jar -htmlsuite
>   "*firefox" "http: //www.google.com/"
>   C:\TestSelenium\TestSuiteThree.html  C:\TestSelenium\results\
>   TestResult.html
>
> 10:55:36.713 INFO - Java: Sun Microsystems Inc. 20.2-b06
>
> 10:55:36.713 INFO - OS: Windows 7 6.1 x86
>
> 10:55:36.719 INFO - v1.0.1 [2696], with Core v@VERSION@ [@REVISION@]
>
> 10:55:36.771 INFO - Version Jetty/5.1.x
>
> 10:55:36.772 INFO - Started
>   HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server /driver]
>
> 10:55:36.772 INFO - Started
>   HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
>
> 10:55:36.773 INFO - Started HttpContext[/,/]
>
> 10:55:36.779 INFO - Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:4444
>
> 10:55:36.780 INFO - Started org.mortbay.jetty.Server@901887
>
> 10:55:36.930 INFO - Preparing Firefox profile...

even after 15 - 20 min nothing happens!!
had anynone came across this kinda issue?? 
any favour is greatly appreciated.......

Comment: Post code which you used.

Comment: In my experience, Selenium servers which are older than the Firefox you're using often fail to start it up correctly. Can you upgrade to the newest version of the server - 2.28.0?